# Restore to Windows Update

Tags: backup, windows-10, system-restore

I have Windows 10, and I wish restore my machine to some point before when I got a virus.

I never manually created a backup, but under `Control Panel > Create a Restore Point > System Restore > Next`, I appear to have the option to restore to a Windows Update that took place before I got a virus.

If I choose this option, will all my personal files and programs be restored, or will it just be the system files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System Restore do not  destroy your saved documents or recieved e-mail. And proccess is absolutly reversible.

[image]

**But if you was infected by a virus you have a 99.9% of chance to have infected/deleted your current restore points.**

> UPDATE:

**What is the point of System Restore?.**

> System Restore helps you restore your computer's system files to an
>   earlier point in time. It's a way to undo system changes to your
>   computer without affecting your personal files, such as e‑mail,
>   documents, or photos.
>
> Sometimes, the installation of a program or a driver can cause an
>   unexpected change to your computer or cause Windows to behave
>   unpredictably. Usually, uninstalling the program or driver corrects
>   the problem. If uninstalling doesn't fix the problem, you can try
>   restoring your computer's system to an earlier date when everything
>   worked correctly.

[Reference](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-system-restore#1TC=windows-7) (is about windows 7 but the feature transcend since Windows XP until current windows 10.)

Comment: Then what is the point of system restore...?

Comment: System Restore will restore "system" files.  Your personal files are not system files.

Comment: Does Windows 10 have a built-in function for making complete backups?

Comment: updated, and @Steven is alright.

Comment: @JoelA.Christophel if you mean about a full disk backup probably no.

Comment: Control Panel > File History> System Image Backup. Why don't I find these things out before things get messed up?

Answer (score 1):

> [What types of files does System Restore Change](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-types-of-files-does-system-restore-change)
>
> System Restore can make changes to Windows system files, registry
>   settings, and programs installed on your computer. It also can make
>   changes to scripts, batch files, and other types of executable files
>   on your computer. **Personal files, such as documents, e‑mail, photos,
>   and music files, are not changed.**